# Java Pig Latin sentence translator using Queues

Tags: java, queue, translate, apache-pig, fifo

I am very new to Java and am trying to create a program to translate a sentence into Pig Latin, moving the first letter of the word to the end and appending "y" at the end if the first letter was a vowel and "ay" at the end otherwise. I am required to use a queue for this. Currently my program is just terminating and I was wondering if anyone might be able to spot where I am going wrong or where to head next. Thanks!

import MyQueue.QueueList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PigLatin
  {

```
public static void main (String[] args)
 {


    Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);

    QueueList word = new QueueList();

    String message;
    int index = 0;
    char firstch;
    System.out.print ("Enter an English sentence: ");
    message = scan.nextLine();
    System.out.println ("The equivalent Pig Latin sentence is: ");

    firstch = Character.toLowerCase(message.charAt(0));


            if (firstch != 'a' && firstch != 'e' && firstch != 'i' && firstch != 'o' && firstch != 'u' 
                    && firstch != ' ')
                {
                    for (index = 1; index < message.length(); index++)

                        {
                            word.enqueue(new Character(message.charAt(index)));
                        }

                    word.enqueue(new Character (firstch));
                    word.enqueue(new Character ('a'));
                    word.enqueue(new Character ('y'));
                    word.enqueue(new Character(' '));

                }

            else if (firstch == 'a' || firstch == 'e' || firstch == 'i' || firstch == 'o' || firstch == 'u')
            {
                while (message.charAt(index) != ' ')
                {
                for (index = 1; index < message.length(); index++)
                        {   
                            word.enqueue(new Character(message.charAt(index)));
                        }
                }
                word.enqueue((firstch));
                word.enqueue( ('y'));
                word.enqueue((' '));
            }
            else if (message.charAt(index) == ' ')
            {
                index++;
                firstch = message.charAt(index);
            }



    while (!word.empty())
        System.out.print(word.dequeue());

}
```

}

And here is the QueueList class from the MyQueue package:

```
// QueueList.java
//
// Class QueueList definition with composed List object.    

package MyQueue;

public class QueueList {

    private List a_queue;

    public QueueList() {
        a_queue = new List( "queue" );
    }

    public Object peek() throws EmptyListException {
        if (a_queue.isEmpty())
            return null;
        else
            return a_queue.getFirstObject();
    }

    public void print() {
        a_queue.print();
    }

    public void enqueue(Object object) {
        a_queue.insertAtBack(object);
    }

    public Object dequeue() throws EmptyListException {
        return a_queue.removeFromFront();
    }

    public boolean empty() {
        return a_queue.isEmpty();
    }

}
```

Comment: Could you please run the formatter on your code? It's a bit difficult to trace your conditionals.

Comment: Indents fixed. The ctrl-k indent doesn't play well with tabs, apologies for mucking up the first edit.

Comment: Thank you for the indentation help. I have edited it to the latest version of my program which currently will not translate and instead print out exactly what was typed in.

Comment: I've updated the answer below.

Answer (score 2):

You are not resetting index to 0 before entering your second while loop. Since `index == message.length()` after the first loop ends, the second loop terminates immediately.

Edit: Re: Your latest update.

In your second loop you only dequeue the first message.length() characters from the word queue. If you've added -ay to the end you won't see it. Instead, loop on the length of the queue, not the length of the input message:

```
while (!word.empty())
    System.out.print(word.dequeue());
```

I can spot numerous other issues with your logic (you are not removing the first letter and you are not processing individual words in the sentence), but the above changes should be enough to get you printing what's on the queue and send you on your way debugging.

Comment: I have fixed that (thank you very much for catching it) and uploaded an edited version but my program is only printing the sentence I enter with the first letter of the sentence at the end. Any suggestions?

Comment: Thank you, Jason. I am not entirely sure how to process individual words but will look into it.

Comment: I have a question about my for loops. Are those incorrect because I should not be setting index = 1 to process the individual words?

Comment: Also, the reason I had a while loop around the whole thing at the beginning was I thought to process the individual words but this is the wrong thing to do?

Comment: What I would do is write a method that changes a single word to Pig-Latin. Take your input sentence, and check out String.split(). Experiment with it. You can use that to separate a sentence into an array of words. Convert each word, then put them back together to make a sentence. The reason you are using 1, btw, is to skip over the first letter -- that seems reasonable to me. Write down your algorithm on a piece of paper, work through the steps, then translate that to Java.